Dom Elements on Top of Phaser canvas
Can I make only a selective DOM elements on top of canvas, not all DOM elements?
I tried searching on google but the answer everywhere is not clear but somewhat "NO". I've only basic understanding of phaser. I'm using version phaser 3.55.2 with reactjs.
I know I can either have DOM elementes on top of phaser canvas or phaser canvas on top of DOM.
I've grid lines and other objects(draggable) made using phaser graphics and then some DOM elements below canvas. So the issue is grid lines are appearing on top of DOM elements which I don't want.
phaserDOM.style.zIndex = '-10';
screenshot of dom below canvas
Then I changed the above code to phaserDOM.style.zIndex = '10'; and it takes DOM elements above canvas and it's perfect like below
screenshot of dom above canvas
But now, in second case, the objects are not draggable because they are below DOM.
I want to ask can I make only a selective DOM elements on top of canvas, not all DOM elements?
In simpler words, I want the white rectangle to appear on top of grid lines and at the same time, my orange objects should be draggable too.
I've tried setting zIndex of the element too but it doesn't work.
const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.width = '100px';
    el.style.height = '100px';
    // el.style.zIndex = '9999';
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    const t = this.add.dom(100, 100, el);
    // t.setDepth(999);

Below is my phaser config file
import Phaser from 'phaser';

import GameScene from './GameScene';

export function getDummyGame() {
  const config = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    parent: 'dummy',
    scale: {
      mode: Phaser.Scale.RESIZE,
      autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    },
    dom: {
      createContainer: true,
      behindCanvas: false,
    },
    transparent: true,
    scene: [GameScene],
  };

  return new Phaser.Game(config);
}



The short answer (out-of-the-box) as far as I know, NO.
That said, you could make small workaround using an invisible GameObject and "on drag" just update the position the DOMElement. Is not perfect, but could work for some usecases.
Mini Demo Example:


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

    class TestScene extends Phaser.Scene {
        create() {
            this.add.text(10, 10, 'Drag the Red DOMElement', )
                .setScale(1.5)
                .setColor('#000000')
                .setOrigin(0)
                .setStyle({ fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial' });
            const domGOSize = 50;
            const el = document.createElement('div');
            el.style.width = `${domGOSize}px`;
            el.style.height = `${domGOSize}px`;

            el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            const domGO = this.add.dom(100, 80, el);
            this.add.line(0, 0, 0, 0, 600, 200, 0x0);

            this.workaroundHelper = this.add.rectangle(domGO.x, domGO.y, domGOSize, domGOSize);

            this.workaroundHelper.setInteractive({ draggable: true, hitArea: new Phaser.Geom.Rectangle(domGO.x, domGO.y, domGOSize, domGOSize) });

            this.workaroundHelper.on('drag', function (pointer, dragX, dragY) {
                domGO.x = dragX;
                domGO.y = dragY;
            });
        }
    }

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.CANVAS,
        parent: 'phaser-example',
        width: 536,
        height: 183,
        dom: {
            createContainer: true,
            behindCanvas: false,
        },
        transparent: true,
        scene: [TestScene],
    };

    new Phaser.Game(config);
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="phaser-example" style="margin:10px;"></div>



